# open .html instead of php using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I am using cakephp and now I need to do a inner redirect to an .html if the file exists inside a cache folder.

So, lets say there is a controller CTRL and action ACT, the url for it is:
domain.com/ctrl/act
Now, I want my htaccess to check if there is an .html inside teh cache folder with the same name of the controller and the action, like:
/cache/ctrl/act.html
if the file exists, just send it and don't touch the php.
I got it to work but now the cakephp is not being processed, the server returns a 500 error.
Can you please help me with this. I also need to check if there is an /index.html within the cachefolder/ctrl/ because the links sometimes has only the controller name.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}.html !^/cache
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cache/$1.html [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to let users directly view files in the cache.

Comment: For security reasons, you don't want people to be able to directly access items in your tmp folder.  It'd be better to write a page in Cake that reads and then displays that file, if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't use the htaccess.
I had to use the beforefilter within AppController.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your first rule to this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/webroot/cache/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ cache/$1.html [L]
```

Comment: it isn't working because document_root is like "localhost" not "localhost/app/webroot", that is where the htaccess is being executed

Comment: So this cache dir is in the document_root/app/webroot/cache ?

Answer (score 0):

Add following in routes.php

```
Router::parseExtensions('html');
```

This will strip off the .html so cakePHP can just work 'normal'